# How to search through lines in a file with Julia

Tags: julia

I need to find a line (row) in a file that contains substring and then do some manipulation on substrings inside the two previous lines, for example:
If there is an "add" sub string is some line, extract the two numerical values from the two previous lines:

```
push contant 17
push constant 5
Add
```

And then print them so I would get:

ouput:

```
17
5
```

I can find the "And" line with eachline and contains:

```
    for ln in eachline(open(f))

        if  (contains(ln,"Add"))
```

But then I am not sure how to go back to the the previous lines in order to extract the desired content

Comment: Can you showed what you have tried? And why it's not working?

Comment: I am new to Julia, I didn't find any way that could search through lines yet. I am familiar only with "eachline" , but it's a problem since I need to find "And" and then go back and that's not how this method working..

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you read a line keep the preceding two lines. Because there will no such lines the first time through the loop set them to `nothing`. Then you can use the value of the second-last-read line to know whether you actually have two previous lines.

```
julia> previous_line==nothing
true

julia> previous_previous_line==nothing
true

julia> for line in eachline(open("sample.txt"))
       if contains(line, "Add") && previous_previous_line!=nothing
       # do something here involving line, previous_line and previous_previous_line
       end
       previous_previous_line, previous_line = previous_line, line
       end
```